# Multi Picklist Validation via Apex?

Tags: apex

I have a question for you

Aim – Create a validation rule, where only 5 picklist values can be choosen

I have the following fields.

- Institutional_Products_A_G__c
- Institutional_Products_G_Z__c
- Intermediary_Products_A_F__c
- Intermediary_Products_G_L__c
- Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c

Each field is a multi picklist. Each field contains over 100 values
I have created the following validation rule (see below) which works, however I am unable to put all the values in due to the size.

Any one got any ideas, how I can get around this ?

```
IF(INCLUDES( Institutional_Products_A_G__c , "Agricultural Fund"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Institutional_Products_A_G__c , "All Maturities Corporate Bond"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Institutional_Products_A_G__c , "All Maturities Index Linked Bond"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Institutional_Products_A_G__c , "Asia Diversified Growth"),1,0) + 

IF(INCLUDES(Institutional_Products_G_Z__c , "Global Property Securities"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES(Institutional_Products_G_Z__c , "Global Resource Equity"),1,0) + 
IF(INCLUDES( Institutional_Products_G_Z__c , "Global Resources Equity Fund"),1,0) > 4
```

Comment: I don't see any formula options.. Is an APEX trigger an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an apex trigger for this. Would look somewhat like this (not tested):

```
trigger ObjectNameCheckProducts on Campaign (before insert, before update) {
    for(Campaign o : Trigger.New){
        Integer counter = 0;

        if(o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c != null) 
           counter += o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c.split(';').size();
        if(o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c != null)
           counter += o.Institutional_Products_G_Z__c.split(';').size();
        if(o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c != null)
           counter += o.Intermediary_Products_A_F__c.split(';').size();
        if(o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c != null)
           counter += o.Intermediary_Products_G_L__c.split(';').size();
        if(o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c != null)
           counter += o.Intermediary_Products_M_Z__c.split(';').size();

        if(counter > 5) o.addError('Max 5 values can be selected from Product lists');
    }    
   }
```

Comment: sorry, put the record identifier before the fieldname: o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c instead of just Institutional_Products_A_G__c. I updated my answer.

Comment: o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c.split(';') would cause NPE if o.Institutional_Products_A_G__c is null. Instead, do "if(x != null) counter += ..."

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, you are very right. I improved my answer with your input.